# Timer plugin won't work after executed once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [This Timer Plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to create a timer once a button is clicked. You can [see it in action here.](http://warcadia.com/game/timer.html) If you notice, when you click any of the purchase buttons twice, it is ignored and will not be executed again. I cannot figure out how to correct this. I need to the timer to restart anytime I click the button once the timer is finished.

**Here is the the HTML I am using on the first button:**

```
<h3 class="protection"><span id="sentryTime">00:00:00</span><a href="javascript:sentry()">Purchase Sentry</a></h3>
```

**And here is the javascript I am using on that button which calls the plugin to create the timer:**

```
function sentry() {
    var dateCreated1 = new Date();
    setCharacterTime(/*hr*/0,/*min*/0,/*sec*/5,/*title*/'sentryTime',dateCreated1)} 


function setCharacterTime(hours, minutes, seconds, title, creationDate) {

    var thisDay = creationDate;
    var year = thisDay.getFullYear();
    var month = thisDay.getMonth();
    var day = thisDay.getDate();
    var aHour = thisDay.getHours();
    var aMinutes = thisDay.getMinutes();
    var aSeconds = thisDay.getSeconds();
    var aMilli = thisDay.getMilliseconds();
    thisDay = new Date(year, month, day, aHour + hours, aMinutes + minutes, aSeconds + seconds, aMilli);
    $('#' + title).countdown({until: thisDay, format: 'HMS', layout: ' {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}', expiryText: 'complete '});
    ;} //end setCharacterTime() function
```

If you need to see the jQuery plugin, [you can find it live here.](http://warcadia.com/game/js/jquery.countdown.js)

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I received from the author of the plugin:

```
function sentry() {
    setCharacterTime('+5s', 'sentryTime');
}
function security() {
    setCharacterTime('+5m', 'securityTime');
}
function police() {
    setCharacterTime('+8m', 'policeTime');
}
function soldier() {
    setCharacterTime('+1h', 'soldierTime');
}
function warrior() {
    setCharacterTime('+1h +45m', 'warriorTime');
}
function setCharacterTime(offset, title) {
    var alertStatement = 'this is supposed to pop up once the timer is complete.';
    $('#' + title).countdown({format: 'HMS', layout: ' {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}', // Initialise
        onExpiry: function() {
            alert(alertStatement);
        }
    }).countdown('option', {until: offset});// Update
}
```